# Android Studio: lint to enforce '&&' instead of '&'?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, operators, linter

Is there an option in Android Studio linter settings to make sure any occurrence of the boolean '&' operator causes an error and only allowing the '&&' operator (while still allowing the & operator for bit-wise operations on numbers)?

**TL;DR**: As you probably know, in Java the '&' operator evaluates both operands before it performs the AND operation, while the '&&' operator stops evaluating operands at the first operand evaluating to false.

I personally find this distinction both confusing and pointless. With the '&&' operator you can do things like:

```
if (a != null && fn (a)) { ... }
```

meaning that `fn` should never be called with a value of *null*. If I accidentally write:

```
if (a != null & fn (a)) { ... }
```

the whole test is completely meaningless. I want to ensure this kind of typo can never occur. A linter rule would be the perfect way to enforce this.

The linter rule should distinguish between the types of the operands. When `&` is used with numbers, its meaning is a bit-wise *and* operator. I do not want to disallow this, of course, as it's quite useful. Moreover, the OR operators `|` and `||` behave in a similar way, and I want to disallow `|` for booleans while allowing it for numerical operations. So basically:

```
int a = (3 & 4);              // OK
boolean b = (true && false);  // OK
boolean c = (true & false);   // linter error, hopefully
int d = (5 | 7);              // OK
boolean e = (true || false);  // OK
boolean f = (true | false);   // linter error, hopefully
```

Comment: `&` is useful in the right circumstances, and is far from being pointless or useless.

Comment: It's all personal taste, I guess. Coming from C++ and JavaScript I'm used to && and I don't see any need for the other one.

Comment: @digorydoo Because sometimes you want to operate on bits?

Comment: True, but the linter rule should _allow_ the & if the operands are numbers and not booleans, of course.

Comment: it can also be used for boolean and the difference between the && is that both sides are evaluated regardless of the left result

Comment: Quite right. That's what I want to disallow, basically.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an option in Android Studio linter settings to make sure any occurrence of the boolean '&' operator causes an error and only allowing the '&&' operator?

The short answer is "no."

You can always write your own lint rules (see [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules) for a sample), but this is not a default option in IntelliJ.

This isn't a matter of "personal taste" either. `&` and `&&` both exist for a reason, just like `|` and `||`.

When it comes to boolean statements, you are correct on the difference. However, the fundamental difference is that `&` is a bitwise "and" while `&&` is a logical "and."

There are plenty of situations in which someone might want a bitwise "and," so making its use a blanket error is not a good idea. The most common use case is using it as a mask.

For example, MotionEvent's `getAction()` method returns an integer with both the pointer index and the action. To get the action, you need to mask the return value like so: `getAction() & ACTION_MASK`.

Comment: I updated the question to make sure I only want to disallow & for boolean operands. In my opinion, there is no use for & _with boolean operands_, but of course the bitwise operator is quite useful.